# Can't use variable from anonymous function outside scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple setup:

```
var genres;
$.get('/api/genres', '', function (response) {
    genres = response.data
}, 'json');
$("#genre").tagit({
    availableTags: genres //this doesn't work
});
```

For some reason the `genres` variable is not accessible inside the `tagit` method. How would I achieve this?

Comment: `$.get` is an asynchronous function. Place your `$("#genre").tagit` line instead of the callback.

Comment: Asynchronous call, `genres` is not defined until `.get` is done.

Comment: By putting `$("#genre").tagit({ availableTags: genres });` inside `function (response) {`. Ajax request is asynchronous. Asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is asynchronous. It's not that `genres` is not accessible inside `.tagit`. Your problem is that by the time you try to use it, it's still unassigned. A way to fix it would be moving your `.tagit` function inside the callback:

```
var genres;
$.get('/api/genres', '', function (response) {
    genres = response.data
    $("#genre").tagit({
        availableTags: genres //this doesn't work
    });
}, 'json');
```

I also recommend reading [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)'s documentation.